# What does "ICON=setup.EXE,1" mean in autorun.inf?

Tags: windows, autorun

What does the following line mean?

```
ICON=setup.EXE,1
```

I found it in `autorun.inf` file.

Essentially, what does the `", 1"` mean or indicate?

Comment: An executable or DLL can contain multiple icons. The number is an index to which specific icon should be selected.

Comment: It's the icon index. A simple google for "autorun.inf" turns up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200(v=vs.85).aspx as the second hit.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/05/10007461.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Inside an `.exe` file you can include "resources" (for example, a bitmap).

The line just tells "search in setup.exe the second resource".

Comment: it is the second icon if you specify 1
because the index is zero based (0 is the first icon)

Comment: This is not quite correct. It means to use the **icon** at index #1. Not "resource", but *icon* - IOW, the second **icon**. It **only** refers to icons.

Answer (score 2):

That means that the autorun.inf file should use the *second* icon defined for the executable file named setup.EXE.

So in windows explorer the inf file will have that icon.

**Update:**

Resources inside an executable or DLL are zero based indexed.

Comment: First icon, or second?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the second  ? since indexing begins at 0 ?

Comment: That was the implication of my comment :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter, you're right but I didn't read your comment :)